# setting a multi-line value in terraform variables

Tags: terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a beanstalk and use this as part of the [aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment) terraform resource:

```
  setting {
    namespace = "aws:elb:policies:PublicKey"
    name      = "PublicKey"
    value     = var.PUBLICKEY
```

The value of the **var.PUBLICKEY** should be in this format:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
asdhjasd
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

May I ask if you have tried to set a variable with this kind of format? Or is terraform allow to use this kind of format as a variable on tfvars section?

Comment: Public key should be single line string. Example is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/create-load-balancer-policy.html).

Comment: Thanks again @Marcin! it solved the deployment issue

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: You can change the accepted answer to Martins answer. Its better.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The value of the `PublicKey` should be a **single line string** without `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----` as shown in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/create-load-balancer-policy.html).

Comment: thanks @Marcin, I followed the format on how the value is used on aws cli and applied to to terraform, it worked as expected. Thanks again for your recommendation

Answer (score 30):

Although the answer for this case was to make it a single-line string, the question here seems likely to attract searches for multi-line strings in Terraform variables in general, so this answer is for anyone who ends up here in a situation where you *can't* just make it a single-line string.

When setting variables within the Terraform language itself (inside `module` blocks) or in [`.tfvars` files](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variable-definitions-tfvars-files), you can use [Heredoc Strings](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#heredoc-strings) to write a multi-line string value:

```
example = <<-EOT
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
asdhjasd
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOT
```

When setting a variable value [on the command line](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#variables-on-the-command-line) or [via environment variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#environment-variables), Terraform just uses the value it recieves literally as given and so the solution would be to learn how to write a string containing newlines in the syntax of your shell or in some other programming language you're using to run Terraform with environment variables set. For typical Unix-style shells you can write quotes `'` around a multi-line string in order to make the newlines be interpreted literally:

```
export TF_VAR_example='-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
sajldlkuewindasmASL/aisudoiasumasdnowqeuoi@kajsdlkausKJDolkejpwr
asdhjasd
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
'
```

...but either way this ends up being a problem for whatever shell or other program you're launching Terraform from, not for Terraform itself, and so it's not possible to give a generic answer that would work for all situations. Writing a `.tfvars` file is the most predictable way to do it, because then Terraform itself is responsible for parsing it.

Comment: Thanks @Martin! I'll try this out too

Comment: This works, special attention to official heredocs link: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/strings.html#heredoc-strings

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on Martin Atkins's response but his suggestion can also be extended to situations where Terraform needs to call a bash script:

```
data "external" "test" {
  program = ["bash", "test.sh"]

  query = {
    pca_cert = "'${data.aws_acmpca_certificate_authority.pca.certificate}'"
  }
}
```

Notice the single quotes enclosing the `${data.aws_acmpca_certificate_authority.pca.certificate}` variable

Comment: this for this solution too